# Случайная выборка с изъятием по весам из бесконечной последовательности. Как такое сделать?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Если есть ограниченное множество с весами, то случайный выбор из него по весу не является проблемой. Если упрощенно, то где-то так:

```
double r = double(rand())/RAND_MAX * sum_of_weights;
for (int ii = 0; ; ++ii)
    if (r < weights[ii])
        return ii;
    else
        r -= weights[ii];
```

Но если множество большое, и нужно изъятие из множества при выборе, то такой алгоритм становится тяжелым. А если множество вообще неограниченное, то такое вообще не применимо.

Думаю этот вопрос решается посредсвом использования `std::multimap<double,T,std::greater<double>>`. Для поступающего нового значения оценивается вес, этот вес случайно модифицируется, и после этого добавляется в `multimap`.

Выбор проиходит из итератора `begin()` - в этот элемент уже будет заложена случайная составляющяя. После выбор удаляется - `mm.remove(mm.begin())`

При превышении критического размера множества, его можно отсекать с наименьших значений `mm.remove(--mm.end())`. А новые элементы, имеющие модифицированный вес меньший чем наименьший `rbegin()->first` в множество вообще не добавляются.

Вопрос, как нужно производить случайную модификацию веса? Какой д.б. алгоритм расчета случайной составляющей, что бы значение имело приближенно примерно такую же вероятность быть выбранным, как при первоначальном простом алгоритме?

Если множество неограниченное, то предположительно, какждое изъятие из `begin()` увеличивает немного модификацию последующих добавляемых весов, что бы прежние значения по немногу устаревали. Если это увеличение превысит размерность, что будет потеря точности double, то множество можно переформировать с пересчетом.

Comment: не очень понял задачу, да и на плюсах не пишу. Но если вопрос в выборе топ Х из бесконечного множества, но самый стандарнтый способ для этого - очередь с приоритетом. Например, для получения ТОП Х самых больших значений, заполняете очередь и как только в ней будет (Х+1) элемент - удаляете минимальный. Повторять пока последовательность не кончится.

Comment: Почти так, только нужна случайная веборка по весам, а не четко по максимальным весам. Я подправил название темы, чтобы акцентировалось на этом внимание.

Comment: Сумма весов ограничена? Нет - задача поставлена некорректно. Да - решение приведено выше.

Comment: Стройте дерево отрезков, но не для весов объектов (они не уникальны), а для производящих функций весов (т.е. для суммы весов всех объектов с индексом меньше  заданного).  Для выборка: генерируем случайное число от 0 до суммы весов, делаем lover_bound. Сложность вставки/удаления/поиска случайного - все: O(log(N)). нельзя только удалить объект по ID.

Comment: @Chorkov В данном случае потребуется пересчитывать дерево отрезков при удалениях из множества. А мне как раз нужно, чтобы каждое выбранное знаение удалялось из множества. В результате лучше не будет.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy А если выборка не бесконечна и сумма коэффициентов определена, то как Вы бы предложили формировать коэффициент без перебора всего множества на каждый выбор? Так чтобы за один проход сформировать и всех разместить в упорядоченное множество. Формирование дерева отрезков не подходит, нужно именно алгоритм коэффициента.

Comment: Из коэффициентов формируете массив накопительных сумм (один раз, *O(N)*). В нём двоичный поиск случайного вещественного числа из *[0, sum)* (много раз, *O(logn)*). Найденный индекс - случайный индекс с нужным вам распределением.

Comment: Вы лучше перезадайте вопрос вместо комментария. В ответах кто-нибудь набросает код. На C++ все нужные строительные блоки есть: накопительный массив, двоичный поиск, случайные числа. На всё строк десять уйдет.

Comment: В принципе я сообразил как сделать на основании этих комментариев. Нужно делать не накопительное дерево отрезков, а просто дерево сумм коэффициентов. Т.е. корень содержит сумму его ветвей. Тогда минимизируется логарифмически и поиск и удаление. Ну или просто делать двух уровневые подпачки, если алгоритм дерева окажется сложным в реализации. Скажем 1000 пачек, каждая из которых по 1000 элементов - это уже 1млн. А поиск элемента в этом 1млн будет тогда делаться максимум за 2000 итераций.

Comment: Хотя если бы можно было использовать multimap, то можно было бы отбрасывать заранее со слабым коэффициентом.

Answer (score 0):

Если для каждого отрезка хранить не начало+конец, а только его длину, то при удалении отрезка, предается перестраивать только те отрезки, в которые входит удаляемый (т.е. логарифмическая сложность сложность удаления). При доступе к элементу, двигаясь по дереву от корня к листьям, уменьшаем счетчик на размер пройденного элемента:

```
#include <variant>
#include <memory>
#include <array>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <variant>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename Key, typename Data, size_t ChildsCount=4>
class key_summ_tree
{
    struct empty_node
    {};
    struct data_node
    {
        Key key;
        Data data;
    };
    struct childs_node;
    typedef std::variant< empty_node, data_node, std::unique_ptr<childs_node> > any_node;
    struct childs_node
    {
        Key key_summ;
        size_t size;
        std::array< any_node, ChildsCount > childs;
    };

    any_node root = empty_node{};


    static size_t _size(const empty_node& ) { return 0;}
    static size_t _size(const data_node& ) { return 1;}
    static size_t _size(const std::unique_ptr<childs_node>& i) { return i ? i->size : 0; }
    static size_t size(const any_node& i) { return std::visit( [](auto& ii)->size_t {return _size(ii); }, i); }

    static Key _key_summ(const empty_node& ) { return Key{0};}
    static Key _key_summ(const data_node& i) { return i.key;}
    static Key _key_summ(const std::unique_ptr<childs_node>& i) { return i ? i->key_summ : Key{0}; }
    static Key key_summ(const any_node& i) { return std::visit( [](auto& ii)->Key {return _key_summ(ii); }, i); }

    static Data& _at(empty_node& , Key) { throw std::out_of_range("Key out of range."); }
    static Data& _at(data_node& i, Key) { return i.data; }
    static Data& _at(std::unique_ptr<childs_node>& i, Key k)
    {
        for( any_node& j : i->childs )
        {
            Key j_key = key_summ(j);
            if(k<j_key)
                return std::visit( [k](auto&jj)->Data& { return _at(jj,k); },  j);
            k -= j_key;
        }
            // Сюда можем попасть, если произошла потеря точности 
            // при операциях с ключем с плавоющей точкой.
            // Взятие последнего элемента, предлагаю дописать самостоятельно.     
        throw std::out_of_range("Key out of range.");
    }
    static Data& at(any_node& i, Key k)
    {
        return std::visit( [k](auto& ii)->Data& {return _at(ii,k); }, i);
    }


    static void insert( any_node& i,  data_node&& d )
    {   // не использую std::visit, поскольку  в некоторых ветках меняется 
        // хранимый в variant тип.
        if(std::holds_alternative<empty_node>(i)) 
        {
            i=std::move(d);
        }
        else
        {
            if(std::holds_alternative<data_node>(i))
            {
                data_node tmp = std::get<data_node>( std::move(i) );
                auto new_i = std::make_unique<childs_node>();
                i = std::make_unique<childs_node>( childs_node{ tmp.key, 1, { std::move(tmp) } });
            }

            childs_node& childs = * std::get<std::unique_ptr<childs_node>>(i);
            childs.size += 1;
            childs.key_summ += d.key;
            auto& add_to=* std::min_element( childs.childs.begin(), childs.childs.end(),
                                             [](auto& l, auto& r){ return size(l)<size(r); } );
            insert( add_to, std::move(d) );
        }
    }

    static Key remove( any_node& i,  Key k )
    {
        if(std::holds_alternative<empty_node>(i))
            throw std::out_of_range("Key out of range.");

        else if(std::holds_alternative<data_node>(i))
        {
            Key ret = std::get<data_node>(i).key;
            i = empty_node{};
            return ret;
        }
        else
        {
            childs_node& childs = * std::get<std::unique_ptr<childs_node>>(i);
            if(childs.size==0)
                throw std::out_of_range("Key out of range.");
            for( auto& j : childs.childs )
            {
                Key j_key = key_summ(j);
                if(k<j_key)
                {
                    Key ret = remove(j,k);
                    childs.size -= 1;
                    childs.key_summ -= ret;

                    if(childs.size==0)
                    {
                        i = empty_node{};
                    }
                    else if(childs.size==1)
                    {
                        i = data_node{ key_summ(i), at(i, Key{0} ) };
                    }
                    return ret;
                }
            }
            // Сюда можем попасть, если произошла потеря точности 
            // при операциях с ключем с плавоющей точкой.
            // Взятие последнего элемента, предлагаю дописать самостоятельно.     
            throw std::out_of_range("Key out of range.");
        }
    }


public:
    key_summ_tree() = default;
    key_summ_tree(const key_summ_tree&)=default;
    key_summ_tree(key_summ_tree&&)=default;
    key_summ_tree( std::initializer_list< data_node > list  )
    {
        for( auto&& i : list)
            insert( i.key, i.data );
    }

    size_t size() const { return size(root); }
    Key    key_summ() const { return key_summ(root); }

    Data& at(Key key_summ)
    {
        return at(root, key_summ);
    }
    const Data& at(Key key_summ) const
    {
        return at( static_cast<any_node&>(root), key_summ);
    }
    void insert( Key k, Data&& d )
    {
        insert( root, data_node{ k, std::move(d) } );
    }
    void remove( Key k )
    {
        remove(root, k);
    }
};
```